# Unable to install Scala IDE plug-in for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I tried installing the following plugin for Eclipse Juno M20120914-1800:

http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-scala-ide-3.0.x-210x

Am running Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8.2) and my Java & Scala versions are as follows:

```
java version "1.6.0_41"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02-445-11M4107)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-445, mixed mode)

Scala code runner version 2.10.0 -- Copyright 2002-2012, LAMP/EPFL
```

When I tried installing the Scala IDE plug-in, the process was prevented and Eclipse displayed this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e     
(org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e)

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 

Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452 
(org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452)

Java Development Tools Core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637 
(org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637)

Java Development Tools Core 3.7.3.v20120119-1537 
(org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.7.3.v20120119-1537)

Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847 
(org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847)

Java Development Tools Core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456 
(org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456)

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: JDI Debug UI 3.6.100.v20120530-1425 
(org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 3.6.100.v20120530-1425)

To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.100,4.0.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.100.v20120523-1953
(org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.100.v20120523-1953)

To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.8.0,4.0.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Scala Plugin 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e 
(org.scala-ide.sdt.core 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e)

To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.6.0,3.7.10)
Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e 
(org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e)

To: org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 0.0.0

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e 
(org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group 3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e)
To: org.scala-ide.sdt.core [3.0.0.nightly-2_10-201302251757-3951e3e]
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nightly you're trying to install is for Indigo (eclipse 3.7).

See the [downloads page](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html).

The site you want for Juno and scala 2.10 nightly is this one:

http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-scala-ide-juno-210x